# Key encryption in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cryptography, data-protection

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` in ASP.NET Core 2.0 application for data protection. And for the default settings I have added below code in `Startup.cs` file

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDataProtection().ProtectKeysWithDpapi();
        ...
        ...
    }
```

But that code throws an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The 'IXmlRepository' instance could not be found. When an 'IXmlEncryptor' instance is set, a corresponding 'IXmlRepository' instance must also be set.

Did I miss something in this implementation?

Answer (score 8):

You specified how to *encrypt* the keys (the Windows DPAPI implementation of `IXmlEncryptor`) but you did not specify where to *persist* the encryption keys (the `IXmlRepository`). There are various options to persist the keys, for example the file system, registry or some remote location in the cloud.

Try using `PersistKeysToFileSystem()` or `PersistKeysToRegistry()`. I suggest you take a look [at the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2) regarding ASP.NET Core Data Protection configuration.